# listctrl new line for an data item

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I have created a listctrl with some of the data in the listctrl are very long, and instead of showing all of the text it ends with `...`. For example `Att PSSM_r1_0_T is [-10.179077,0.944198]|Att PSSM_r1_0_Y is...`. How would i be able to make it so it shows all of the text. Something like

`Att PSSM_r1_0_T is [-10.179077,0.944198]|Att PSSM_r1_0_Y is 
[-4.820935,9.914433]|Att PSSM_r1_2_I is [-8.527803,1.953804]|Att PSSM_r1_2_K is [-12.083334,-0.183813]|Att PSSM_r1_2_V is 
[-14.112536,5.857771]|1`

As the text is very long I would prefer if it covered more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible to do with a standard listctrl.

Try poking around at the UltimateListCtrl, being a full owner drawn listctrl it has the ability to change the way its looks far more than a standard listctrl.